# Installing Ubuntu on Dell C400 without bootable USB or CD

Tags: system-installation

The Dell laptop I have does not have a CD-ROM drive and if you connect one via USB it's not bootable. The computer is also not bootable from USB as the BIOS does not have this function.

*So is there any way of installing from CD without a reboot?  Or via the web somehow?*

Comment: Can you give us the specific Dell Model number?  Also what OS was shipped with it?

Comment: The only possible option is installing through LAN, if that's even possible, and it tends to be very complicated.

Answer (score 2):

Dell C400 and it has Windows XP. But, I just found out that the only cd rom this laptop will boot from is the one sold separately for the C400. It has a special cable too, it does not use the usb.  I found one on ebay.  So, if that drive boots, I will be installing Linux soon. The bios does allow for cd boot.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with a Dell laptop and fixed it in a very complicated way. Note that this will require an external machine, that you are able to install Ubuntu on. What you want to do is extract your hard drive from your laptop (without damaging it) and plug it into another machine. Once there complete an Ubuntu installation on that drive then power off and plug it back into your laptop **NOTE THAT DEPENDING ON YOUR LAPTOP THIS MAY VOID YOUR WARRANTY,** but you will have Ubuntu